# Twitter Bootstrap inline form spacing

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

[Here is a JSFiddle showing my code in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/MFKBj/)

I want to add a few pixels of spacing between the different parts of the form in the most correct way using Twitter Bootstrap 3 taking responsiveness into consideration. I've looked over the documentation, but it still isn't clear to me what the best way to accomplish this is.

Any ideas?

Here is my current form HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="timezone">Timezone</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="timezone" name="timezone">
      <option value="America/St_Lucia">America/St_Lucia</option>
      <option value="Europe/Nicosia">Europe/Nicosia</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input id="timeformat-0" name="timeformat" value="24" type="radio" />
    19:00
  </label>

  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input checked id="timeformat-1" name="timeformat" value="12" type="radio" />
    7:00 PM
  </label>

  <button class="btn" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: horizontal or vertical spacing? Which elements need to be further apart?

Comment: Horizontal spacing! I'm looking to add about 10 pixels of space between the dropdown and the group of radio buttons as well as some space between the group of radio buttons and the save button. I don't need more space between the radio buttons.

Comment: Try using the Bootstrap Grid (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Comment: @meavo: The reason why I'm hesitant to using the grid is because I don't want to necessarily change the widths of the elements (or groups) as such, I just want the space between them to be slightly wider.

Comment: You're not going to find a Bootstrap input spacing variable. Apply CSS as you like. There are LESS variables for input size, but not spacing.

Comment: @isherwood: Okay, thanks, I'll try that! The reason why I asked was simply because I'm new to the responsive part of CSS design and I want to make sure I "do the right thing" for this particular scenario as the form will be very central to the website's functionality.

Comment: When you take responsive into consideration, you shouldn't be hesitant about changing width/height of elements. Everything should be fluid and dependant of the available space within its container.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can try with `margin` to all direct childrens of  `.form-inline`:

```
.form-inline > * {
   margin:5px 3px;
}
```

View this fiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/MFKBj/10/**

*PD: I only add `!important` in the fiddle to make me sure it's over the bootstrap CSS you don't need this.*

Comment: This is not necessary in Bootstrap 3. You can just wrap the elements in `div.form-group`. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example of using the Bootstrap Grid system. You could apply a bunch of classes to handle the different viewports.

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="sr-only" for="timezone">Timezone</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="timezone" name="timezone">
        <option value="America/St_Lucia">America/St_Lucia</option>
        <option value="Europe/Nicosia">Europe/Nicosia</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input id="timeformat-0" name="timeformat" value="24" type="radio" />
        19:00
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input checked id="timeformat-1" name="timeformat" value="12" type="radio" />
        7:00 PM
      </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question as the OP - he is asking about spacing things out horizontally - BS smashes things together pretty well [as seen here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_inline&stacked=h). Here's my solution:

```
.form-inline label {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I've done it; add minimal spacing to all labels and controls, and use a negative margin on the container to keep everything correctly aligned.

```
.form-inline {
    margin: 0 -3px;
}

.form-inline .form-group label,
.form-inline .form-group input,
.form-inline .form-group select {
    margin: 0 3px;
}
```

Comment: I like your answer better as it provides better overall spacing

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap 4 you have the [Spacing utilities](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/).

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-lg-2">
        <!-- column-small-50%, margin-bottom-large -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 3, you can wrap the elements in a `div.form-group`, like so:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input id="timeformat-0" name="timeformat" value="24" type="radio" />
    19:00
  </label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input checked id="timeformat-1" name="timeformat" value="12" type="radio" />
    7:00 PM
  </label>
</div>
```

You can see this in this section of the Bootstrap 3 docs:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-inline

Comment: This doesn't provide the spacing the question is looking for.

Comment: Doesn't provide the space and is already being used in the original question